# Synology NAS Backup to Azure Blob Storage - used space and billing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, nas, synology

I am using Azure Blob Storage to backup Synology NAS.

My used space on NAS is 810 GB but my used space in Azure Blob Storage is 2642GB. I am using STANDARD IO - BLOCK BLOB (GB) - LOCALLY REDUNDANT.

Does someone know why there is such a big difference in stored data?

Thanks,
A

Comment: I'm wondering if you're taking blob snapshots? That could be one reason of high space consumption in blob storage.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I didn't took the blob snapshot at any point in time..

Comment: Have you used a tool like [Storage Explorer](https://storageexplorer.com) to look at the contents of your storage account?

Comment: @ArturG, Azure provide billable storage size only for the entire storage account through the [storage metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343258.aspx). I think you can try to check the metrics for transactions & capacity to know the actual reason of space consumption, and also combined with [storage billing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting to rotate the backup data in Hyper Backup in Synology NAS. It was setup to keep 227 restore points, so the data in Azure Blob storage was growing every time the backup was taken.

I've change the settings in Synology and it's free up used storage.